# pdf is not scaling in pdfview android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using library `Dmitry-Borodin/pdfview-android` for showing pdf in android. My view is showing pdf correctly but the scaling of pdf doesnot seems to be working.

```
pdfView!!.fromFile(file!!).scale(500f).show()
```

Above is my code for showing pdf and scaling it.

With scaling I mean that width of pdf is quite small than that of device screen width

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Library, Please go through ImageView Component.

You need to create a Bitmap that matches the aspect ratio of the Page. It's best to match the dimensions of the ImageView as well:

```
            PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
            PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(0);
            int pageWidth = page.getWidth();
            int pageHeight = page.getHeight();
            float scale = Math.min((float) REQ_WIDTH / pageWidth, (float) REQ_HEIGHT / pageHeight);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (pageWidth * scale), (int) (pageHeight * scale), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: for now I am unable to make that change. if you can help me with library please do

Comment: But I will test your suggestion separately

Comment: Okay glad to help buddy, Let me check with your library and revert back to you